# Parsing data packets in LabVIEW

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, packet, labview

I'm trying to parse data from a stream of data packets that are in this format:

[image]

What would be the best way to go about doing this in LabVIEW?

Comment: And what is exactly the problem in your case? Just take string, use string functions, and parse the data. What did you try so far? Do you get string in brackets, one by one? Or string which contains multiple data in brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use "Scan from string" function to parse that data. Be aware of proper decimal point character.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I actually need this to work without a line feed between packets.  I've tried modifying your code using ">" as the delimeter instead of the line feed constant and also removing ">" from the end of format string, but for some reason this gives me an error.  Have any ideas why this won't work?

Comment: You might want to repeadetly split the string using the "Search/Split String" function to split it by the ">" char and then parse each of the resulting elements using the method described in the answer. Also make sure, that you check for errors on the parsing part, otherwise you might work with invalid data for an invalid input string.